# Customized colormap on Mat in Emgu.CV in C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using CvInvoke.ApplyColorMap to assign a colormap on my grayscale mat (srcMat, 50 by 50, 8-bit unsigned integer, single channel). But it seems there are only built in colormaps in "ColorMapType Enumeration". Can I have customized colormap to assign?

Example codes:

```
Mat dstMat = new Mat(50, 50, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
CvInvoke.ApplyColorMap(srcMat, dstMat , Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorMapType.Jet);
```

In the example codes, I am using built-in colormap "Jet". Can someone advise how to use customized colormap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a 256x1 mat with your custom colormap, this one goes from green to red:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> ApplyCustomColorMap(Image<Gray, byte> imin)
{


Bgr col0 = new Bgr(Color.Green);
Bgr col1 = new Bgr(Color.Red);

Matrix<byte> mtB = new Matrix<byte>(256, 1);
Matrix<byte> mtG = new Matrix<byte>(256, 1);
Matrix<byte> mtR = new Matrix<byte>(256, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    double p = (double)i / 256.0;
    double q = 1 - p;

    mtB.Data[i, 0] = (byte)(q * (double)col0.Blue + p * (double)col1.Blue);
    mtG.Data[i, 0] = (byte)(q * (double)col0.Green + p * (double)col1.Green);
    mtR.Data[i, 0] = (byte)(q * (double)col0.Red + p * (double)col1.Red);
}
VectorOfMat vct = new VectorOfMat();
vct.Push(mtB);
vct.Push(mtG);
vct.Push(mtR);
Mat mm2 = new Mat(256, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
CvInvoke.Merge(vct, mm2);

var colorMappedImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(img_colormap.Size);
CvInvoke.ApplyColorMap(imin, colorMappedImage, mm2);
return colorMappedImage;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I want.